# When we use Earthing and Bonding?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-protection, shock, grounding

I read in some [articles](http://www.electricalsafetyfirst.org.uk/guides-and-advice/around-the-home/earthing-and-bonding/) the difference between the earthing and bounding. But i still don't understand when we use bonding. I think Earthing is the more important part to grounding and protect from electrical shock. Any examples to understand the difference ? can we use bounding without earthing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the bonding and earthing example is the watching machine in the kitchen.

If a washing machine were to develop a ground fault, the current would travel down the earthing path.   Without the earth connection, the metal outer casing of the washing machine could become 'live'.  The principal of earthing is to prevent this situation occurring, by limiting the duration of touch voltages.

Bonding is a connection of all metallic parts using a protective bonding conductor.  So taking our faulty washing machine above, if you were to to touch it and then touch a metal tap in your kitchen, you would be the earth path and could receive a potentially life threatening electric shock.  The lack of bonding (as well as earthing) would create a chain effect of all metallic parts becoming live in the kitchen.  This would also include all pipework too.  It’s quite a scary scenario which is why earthing and bonding are so essential and why it is important to know the difference between the two.

Bonding is intended to limit the magnitude of touch voltages while earthing is intended to limit the duration of touch voltages.

Comment: Although we prefer bonding because of the reasons mentioned it is not always possible. See my extended answer.

Answer (score 2):

Earthing connects the frame of the apparatus to the earth wire incorporated in the connection or in some instances a complete separate earth connection.

The earth connections are bonded if there is a direct wire connection between two or more different apparatus frames.

Example:

If one apparatus is connected to an earthed outlet and the second one also then both are bonded due to the combined earth connection incorporated in the wiring.

If on the other hand one apparatus is connected to an earthed outlet and the second one has it's own independant earth connection than there is no direct wire connection between these apparatus and therefore they are not bonded.

Bonding is important for safety reasons.

Example:

If a person touches two not bonded apparatus and one of them has an electric failure and an earth failure than he or she can be electrocuted only by touching both.

Exeptions.
In very large factory installations bonding is not always possible. This because the incomming mains supplies do not always have the same origin. 
A part of the factory receives its power directly from the low voltage network (the transformer is remote) and a different part of the factory uses its own transformer with its own earth. 
In such situation bonding is not possible since it would create very large equalizing currents.